# SFDX: Get Apex Debug Logs is not getting my own log

Tags: debugging, apex-debugger

I turned on "SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger", and then I run through my code to see if there's debug logs and there is debug logs generated. However, when I try to "SFDX: Get Apex Debug Logs" nothing is showing up in the list for my user name in VS Code? Is there any configuration I need to specify in VS Code?

[image]

Comment: `SFDX: Turn On Apex Debug Log for Replay Debugger`, by default, turns on the trace flag only for the next 1 hour. Check if the trace flag is still active for your user account. Also, run `sfdx update`, restart VS Code and try getting the logs again.

Comment: I was able to figure out. Our org just had way too many error logs. I had to Delete All Debug Logs
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" > out.csv
sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Our org just have too much logs and running the following resolved the issue.

- Delete All Debug Logs

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" > out.csv
sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv
```